# CodeIgniter Active Record: how to use "set" method with mysql functions

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have my query something like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(UNHEX('some_value'));
```

How can I pull this query off using codeigniter active record, specifically the '$this->db->set' function

```
this->db->set('password', $value); // How do I insert the mysql function here
$this->db->insert('tbl');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert) - it states that if you need some value unescaped, you should set the third parameter in set() to false. Like this:

```
$this->db->set("password", "UNHEX('".$value."')", FALSE);
```